# Python 3.6 API while loop to json script not ending

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a loop via API call to a json string since each call is limited to 200 rows.  When I tried the below code, the loop doesn't seem to end even when I left the code running for an hour or so.  Max rows I'm looking to pull is about ~200k rows from the API.

```
bookmark=''
urlbase = 'https://..../?'
alldata = []
while True:
    if len(bookmark)>0:
        url = urlbase + 'bookmark=' + bookmark
    requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password'))
    data = response.json()
    alldata.extend(data['rows'])
    bookmark = data['bookmark']
    if len(data['rows'])<200:
        break
```

Also, I'm looking to filter the loop to only output if json value 'pet.type' is "Puppies" or "Kittens."  Haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try to output the values of `url` and `len(data['rows'])` in each round of the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you breaking when you get less than 200 rows because that's an indication that there were no more data to consume?

Comment: @jsfan basically after looping 200 rows every API call, I'd like for the loop to break once there are less than 200 rows left to collect in "alldata"

Comment: Your approach actually looks correct if you expect the response to eventually contain less than 200 lines. Have you ever confirmed that that ever happens? Does the bookmark really contain what you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The break condition for you loop is incorrect. Notice it's checking `len(data["rows"])`, where **`data` only includes rows from the most recent request**.

Instead, you should be looking at the **total** number of rows you've collected so far: `len(alldata)`.

```
bookmark=''
urlbase = 'https://..../?'
alldata = []
while True:
    if len(bookmark)>0:
        url = urlbase + 'bookmark=' + bookmark
    requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password'))
    data = response.json()
    alldata.extend(data['rows'])
    bookmark = data['bookmark']
    # Check `alldata` instead of `data["rows"]`,
    # and set the limit to 200k instead of 200.
    if len(alldata) >= 200000:
        break
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the OP right but your code would just break on the first iteration if it doesn't get a response of more than 200k lines.

Comment: @CarolynConway That works!  You're a life saver, many thanks!

Comment: @n4zy By what you commented above, this doesn't really solve the problem the way you wanted. Carolyn's code will just keep requesting until it has received a total of 200k rows. That might work for you but isn't exactly what you described above.

Comment: @jsfan true, it will limit to outputting 200k rows even though I will have more in the future since the data grows monthly.  Right now, I'm manually adding the exact # of rows I need, but would like to automate at some point.  Any ideas?